# Working with WebLogic in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, weblogic, eclipse-juno

Is there a way to work with WebLogic in Juno until Oracle releases OEPE for Juno?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [forum](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2396316), OEPE for Juno (4.2) is undergoing final testing. It should be available in a few weeks, yet there is no guarantee.

Comment: Now it is available for both 3.8 and 4.2: http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/1723375